# Reporting a Username

Tags: support, status-completed, users, moderation

I'm not sure exactly how to report a user name.  [I read an answer suggesting that you flag something in their activity as `other`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178159/161479), but this one doesn't have any.

[Here is the account in question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573805/fbsucksdick-foreverandever), it probably won't make you cry yourself to sleep but I don't think it belongs here... especially on a blank account.

Comment: How did you even run across the account anyways? We generally don't care about users who have never contributed anything to the site whatsoever because their name isn't attached to anything.

Comment: @animuson, yup, the only profile view is mine + yours + caching, right? ;)

Comment: @Gary, is the username the problem? Is it a problem because of the verb or the noun? Or maybe the implication that it is forever? Inquiring minds want to know :p

Comment: A _suck poppet_?

Comment: @πάντα, maybe ;) But the only badge is `Enthusiast`, which still proves that user has visited the site for 30 days straight. The otherwise lack of activity makes me suspect Gary was only looking for naughty words on the user search page.

Comment: @Robert, I suppose you didn't nuke that user simply because of their nick. Was that an additional offense to something?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I hope _@Robert_ nuked this user because of my concerns ;-) ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey May be this question deserves some decent screenshots left, to make others understand what actually was going on.

Comment: Yup, I was actually asking for more information here. Was that really a sockpuppet that could be identified under five minutes? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It was nothing. The account had absolutely zero activity on it aside from that silver badge.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ha, I wasn't searching naughty words giggling like a school kid.  There's a user I had been watching, who after a few downvotes, changed his name to "this community sucks".

Comment: @Gary, ah, it would have been interesting to know that, because that user you've been watching could have changed their nick because of specific events, and avoiding such events can help improve this community in the future. Was the user hostile from the get-go? Can you tell us more?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, he just asked a question that got a ton of down votes and posted an rant answer.  I flagged it, it got deleted, I came back later and he was suspended with a new name.  I was really just curious if he was going to come back.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No screen shot needed, hovering over the link still shows the username in the link target. Unless there was something interesting on the profile itself. Suck poppet... that was funny!